# Flutter : Assigning a collectionGroup to Collection Reference type

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Can I assign a CollectionGroup to a Collection Reference like this
to get the parent document of a subcollection.

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = Firestore.instance.collectionGroup('students');
DocumentReference documentReference = collectionReference.parent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible.  A call to `collectionGroup()` returns a Query object.  A query doesn't have a "parent".

When you execute a [collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query), the matched documents could come from any number of different subcollections with the same name.  You won't know anything until you actually look at the DocumentSnapshot objects that come back.  If you want to know where one of those documents came from, you ask look at the [DocumentSnapshot](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot-class.html) and use its [reference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/reference.html) property to find the [DocumentReference](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) that describes where it exists.  That DocumentReference has a [parent](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference/parent.html) that tells you which collection that individual document is in.