# How to query collection group in the latest version of cloud firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have just migrated to null safety and i found things abit different in cloud firestore's latest version. `^2.4.0`. I am trying to query a collection group but i cant seem to get it right. I have tried going through the docs but i cant find it.

Traditionally it would go like

```
  final CollectionReference myCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collectionGroup('myCollection');
```

then i would go like

```
myCollection.snapshots()
```

Right now `.collectionGroup('')` is not assignable to `CollectionReference` but to `Query<Map<String,dynamic>>`

I would appreciate help on how to get this right.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter : Assigning a collectionGroup to Collection Reference type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417271/flutter-assigning-a-collectiongroup-to-collection-reference-type)

Comment: Not really. I would like to know how to query a collection group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A collection group cannot be assigned to a `CollectionReference`. You'll need to change the type of your `myCollection` variable to be a `Query`:

```
final Query myCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collectionGroup('myCollection');
```

No other changes should usually be needed, as most of the method used on `myCollection` are actually gonna come from the [`Query` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query-class.html) anyway.